# File: Convert Two Columns to a php Array like format

Tags: php, arrays, excel, output

Please see this: http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html.

I have this data in an Excel file in two columns. `Column A` has the Feature Codes while `Column B` has its brief description.

I d' like an array like:

```
 $listOfFeatures = array( 'ADM1'=>'first-order administrative division','ADM1H' => 'historical first-order administrative division');
```

I am thinking maybe a an Excel Macro can do this--output into some .CSV file. The output doesn't have to look like the php array. But something I can easily tweak to make it work.

Any idea?
Thanks.

**update** using `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('feature_code_abbrv.csv'));`

per http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php I think I am getting closer:

```
array(668) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "ADM1" [1]=> string(36) " first-order    administrative division" }
```

but not sure if this the array I can use to populate a dropdown box?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up getting an associative array from the two columns of the Excel file; I need the array only once and so it was worth putting some manual work into it.

1) Save the Excel file with only the two needed-columns into a .CSV file.
2) Run the following code against the .CSV file

```
    function makecsv() {
      return array_map('str_getcsv', file('feature_code_abbrv.csv'));
    }
    $listOfFeaturesGeoNames = array();
    $listOfFeaturesGeoNames = makecsv();
    $outputlist = "outputlistfinal = array(' '=>'None',";
    foreach ($listOfFeaturesGeoNames as $element) {
      $outputlist.="'$element[0]' =>'". $element[1] . '\','; 
    }
```

Above code still yielded an associative array which needed only a little bit more massaging manually. After that assigned the `var_dump` output of that array to a php array and loaded into my form to populate a drop down list. Works perfectly fine!

Hope this helps someone.